# Dubious Tenses in Airline Preflight Speech

Tags: tenses

I fly a lot of places (usually within the United States).  When I take Delta, the flight attendants seem to recite (with minor differences) a prepared preflight speech detailing safety information.

They seem to have a lot of minor grammatical issues, but the most annoying to me is something like the following: "Pull the mask firmly toward you to start the flow of oxygen.  Even though the bag will not inflate, oxygen is flowing." (something similar appears in an [official version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noE1YzvfA08#t=149)).

My main concern here is the tense.  They are saying that the bag "will (not) inflate" (future) but that oxygen "is flowing" (continuing present).  It's surprisingly difficult to come up with a better version, although I thought of a few variations that, if not solving the problem, would at least improve the sound (e.g. "Oxygen flows even if the bag does not inflate.").

Although I can't think of a grammatical reason, I feel like once the imperative tone is dropped (e.g. "[You ]Pull the . . ."), having consistent tenses becomes more important--and not having them becomes more egregious.

The whole thing is supposed to be conditional future also, although tacking the necessary *would* onto each sentence would decrease clarity, so I agree with their choice to leave it implicit.

I'm not so much asking because I don't know whether this is wrong (I'm almost certain it is), but because I'd like to know what the internet thinks of this.  I have never seen anyone else notice this (and because it's so consistent and awkward, I usually visibly cringe).

Comment: All formulaic speech, especially legally-mandated speech like this, contains oddities of expression and usage that feel strange out of their original context. So it's not surprising it's odd; that's one of the reasons for official speech in the first place -- to make you take notice.

Comment: Second, I hate to be the one to tell you, but there are only two tenses in English: present and past. All the rest of the so-called "tenses" are just old fancy names for [a few of the several thousand combinations of auxiliaries and verbs](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html#tenselist) possible in English. So don't worry about mixing them. And don't worry about correctness unless you know the actual rules.

Comment: I think I've sometimes heard it as "Even though the bag _does_ not inflate, ..."

Comment: When you fly to San Francisco, be sure to spend some time in the BART system, where you'll almost certainly hear this announcement at some point: "Report any suspicious packages to the train operator, station agent, or call BART police at 877-679-7000."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a rant.

Comment: @JohnLawler: The linked resource was extremely helpful, but does not the "verb phrase syntax" need to match as well as tense?  @MrHen: I wanted to add the tag `soft-question`, but it doesn't seem to exist on this stackexchange site.  I'll also admit the question isn't exactly productive; after sitting on a plane for some hours surrounded by people yet cutoff from human contact save an awkward preflight announcement, one's writing is not at its best.

Comment: I've always understood this phrasing to use _will_ in the literal, semantic sense of actual willingness, rather than the semantically void sense as a future marker; i.e., even if the bag refuses to inflate.

Comment: Think yourself lucky you don't fly with Japanese airlines *We hope you have enjoyed your fright with us*. And after serving drinks and peanuts, in turbulence, *please hold your drinks in your hand, (and your nuts in your other hand)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be technical you could say:

> Even though the bag will not inflate, oxygen will flow.

-or-

> … oxygen will be flowing at that time.

They just don't sound so great.

My advice, keep your earphones on and listen to music. Order a drink from the flight attendant, and try not to worry about the proper tense.  Worry more about the large metal object's lack of desire to remain airborne except for a few miracles in engineering.

Comment: Well, it would make one special to be probably the first passenger in airline history to be wondering about the grammatical correctness of the pre-flight safety instructions while going down in flames...

Comment: @oerkelens That could be quite true!  Flight Attendant:  "Sir, we need you to remain calm!"  Passenger:  "But, you said oxygen will be flowing!!!!!  FLOWING!!!!!!!!!!!"